# Is Morocco dangerous, in particular for a Jewish American?

Tags: safety, morocco, religion, rabat

I may be travelling to Morocco later this year. I am an American student (not Moroccan by birth, only by inherited citizenship) and my last name is Jewish.

With Morocco: [predicting a "serious terror threat" in the coming months](http://english.alarabiya.net/en/News/2014/07/11/Morocco-ramps-up-security-face-with-serious-terror-threat-.html); the growing number of anti-semitic attacks in recent years; the fact that Morocco is a Muslim country, and the fact that I am American and Moroccans will easily detect that I am ethnically Jewish, is there any danger in travelling to Morocco? I am afraid of being involved in some terrorist plot, very afraid actually.

I would also like to know if Morocco is dangerous in general, for tourists.

By the way, I would be going there four 4 days in April to take part in a math training camp for high school math contests. I don't know yet which city I would be going to, but I assume this camp will be held at a university.

Comment: What do you plan to do in Morocco? There's dangerous floods in the Atlas Mountains at the moment. There's a territorial dispute at the border. Road conditions are horrendous. Some of the remote regions have always been dangerous. More detail on your plans will produce more relevant results.

Comment: Realised your focus is on being a Jewish American in Morocco, rather than the general safety (I hope) so have edited it to be more specific to that. Otherwise it was on track to being put on hold for being broad (see [help] for what questions are considered suitable).  If I got the wrong idea, please do edit as appropriate.

Comment: [There are still some small Jewish communities in Morocco.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moroccan_Jews#Communities_Today) While I haven't been there recently, I travelled there for a month shortly after the 9/11 terror attacks and found it very safe and friendly.

Comment: @blahblah you've edited back in the 'in general' part, but haven't addressed Gayot's concerns.  Is America dangerous, in general? It depends on where you're going, parts of Detroit vs parts of Seattle will vary wildly.

Comment: I'm going to Rabat.

Comment: Morocco among one of the very few Arab counties that has Jews among the population, Moroccan Jews are just living among the people with no problems.

Comment: Rabat felt a lot safer than Casablanca and had less tourists than Marrakesh or Fez so fewer pickpockets etc that usually prey on tourists. But it still has an old Medina so has atmosphere and things to see.

Answer (score 12):

It is safe for all jews.

Jews have been part of the history of Morocco. Maybe they lived there before Islam but a big jew community came to Morocco when they were expelled after Spain took back "Al Andalous" from Muslims, who returned to Morocco as well.

Nowadays, there are aren't as many because of migration to Israel (because of their beliefs they must go to what they call "home", as well as to enhance their quality of life). However, there is an important Jewish community still today in Morocco, and they don't encounter issues.

I can give you some examples of famous Jews in Morocco: Gad El Maleh, a comedian originally from Casablanca, popular with many Moroccans like him. Another of prominance is André Azolay, a consultant to the King.

To conclude, Moroccans do not have any problems with Jews; Jews are part of Morocco. The problems they have can be Israel as a country. But in Morocco, we don't confuse the two, Jews and Israel.

Answer (score 7):

It's not exactly the same, but...

My son's teacher recently visited Morocco. He's very visibly Jewish, and so is his name - and he hasn't had any trouble.

(The big difference, admittedly, is that he was actually born and raised in Morocco, and his family still lives there. Also, he was in Casablanca, whereas you mentioned in your comments that you're going to Rabat.)

You might do well to contact Chabad there for tips and suggestions.

Comment: I am sorry, but what does it mean to be _visibly Jewish_? Are you talking about hasidic jews?

Comment: Many more Jews wear the distinctive kippa (yarmulke) than just Hasids. But as far as the original question, I know many Jews who have visited Morocco, and there were no problems other than those typical of tourism where the infrastructure is shaky and poverty beyond what they were used to.

Answer (score 3):

Serously, Moroccan Jews make 1/3 of Israel and you still think that we are Anti-Semite? We are originally a Jewish country before the coming of Islam. Lots of Jews still live here and lots of them come from Israel to spend their holidays in here each year. So no, you should pass by anytime you want.

Comment: Re your first sentence: One has to wonder, then, what exactly compelled all those Moroccan Jews to leave the country...

Comment: @user438, They have never been expelled, they went to israel by choice. There are also until today a lot of jews living in Morocco and as a Moroccan I have not to say welcome to them because they are home!

Comment: @user438 they left for economical reasons, of course. Morocco , was a poor country who suffered from the european Colonisation Versus israel enjoying the unconditional support from USA .  So those who stayed in my opinion have a very big attachememt to Morocco and have to be greeted for that !

Answer (score 1):

As of today the US State Department has Morocco at **Level 2: Exercise Increased Caution**.

Check their website for future updates and alerts:

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/morocco-travel-advisory.html

Answer (score 1):

Morocco is one of the best and safest country in the world, they live arabs 30% , berbers 50%, jews 10% , haratines, sahraouians, christians and other religions and ethnics ...

As Iam a french jewish landy, I lived in marrakech medina near to jewish mellah,since 10years now and I have so many real friendly moroccan friends and i grow up my business in tourism by managing a riad and a small touristic company for jewish tours and student trips...

I enjoy myself all time, I recommend for you morocco to visit or live .